# loop through folder of PDF files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'd like to loop through a folder of PDF files and insert file into the appropriate text box of a word document.

I couldn't find much online about it, but I tried to model my code on looping through a folder of excel files... I haven't attempted to get it to insert the PDFs but am trying to tackle this problem first. BTW I have Adobe Reader and not Adobe Professional, if that helps.

I debugged the code and the error is on `Set fromPDF = AcroExch.PDDoc.Open(sPath & sFile)`...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub UseTextBox()

Dim reportDoc As Object
Dim str As String
Dim tag As String
Dim pdfName As String

Set reportDoc = ActiveDocument
MsgBox reportDoc

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


'match PDF to figure and insert
Set SelectFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With SelectFolder
        .Title = "Select Directory"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo ResetSettings
        sPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With



sFile = Dir(sPath & "*pdf")
Do While sFile <> ""
    Set fromPDF = AcroExch.PDDoc.Open(sPath & sFile)
    pdfName = sFile


For Each objShape In reportDoc.Shapes
    If objShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
        str = objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        If InStr(str, "(") > 0 Then

            tag = BetweenParentheses(objShape.TextFrame.TextRange)
            MsgBox tag
        End If
    End If
Next objShape
sFile = Dir
Loop

ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating the AcroExch object? I think that might be your issue.

You may need something like:

```
Set MyObject = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
```

Comment: So it turns out that I only have Adobe Reader, which has a limited set of OLE capabilities.. It seems like I won't be able to loop through a folder of PDF files without Adobe Acrobat? I inserted a PDF as an object and recorded the macro, which was fine.... but because I have Reader does this mean I won't be able to automate the process? @Ryan Wildry